# Polymorphic relationships

Tags: php, laravel, database-design, eloquent

I've got a master table called Product with the following columns:

```
id
product_id
product_type
name
price
in_stock
upc
```

Where ’id' and 'product_id' are unique (id is the PK)

I'll have other tables for different kinds of products (types).
All these other tables will have Product’s properties plus
Other properties on their own depending on the type of product
(I.e. clothing, records, etc.).

So I created a Product model using Polymorphic relationships
as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'product_type',
        'name',
        'price',
        'in_stock',
        'upc'
    ];

    public function categorizable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

And, for instance, a records model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Record extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'artist_id',
        'title',
        'label',
        'code',
        'format',
        'number_of_discs',
        'image',
        'description'
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('\App\Product', 'categorizable');
    }

    public function artist()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Artist::class);
    }

    public function track()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Track::class);
    }

    public function getItemDetails(int $itemId): array {

    }

}
```

Whereas the columns for record are:

```
id
artist_id
product_id
title
label
```

This is the best way I could think of relating these tables.

My questions are:

1. Is there a better approach to this specific problem?
2. In this case (using polymorphic relationships), how would I insert a product?
3. How could I query a product in order to return data from
   Both product table and record table? I mean, not a raw query
   Since that I can do, but how to perform this query using
   Eloquent?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfect except `product_id` column in `Record`. You don't need that column, just remove it

> how would I insert a product?

```
$product = Product::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'in_stock' => $request->in_stock
        ]);

$record->products()->save($product);
```

OR

```
$record->products()->create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'price' => $request->price,
                'in_stock' => $request-> in_stock,
                'product_id' => $record->id,
                'product_type' => get_class($record)
            ]);
```

If you need to create both then do it like this

```
$record = Record::create([
          'artist_id' => $request->artist_id
          'title' => $request->title,
          'label' => $request->label,
          'code' => $request->code,
]);

$product = Product::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'price' => $request->price,
                'in_stock' => $request->in_stock
            ]);

$record->products()->save($product);
```

> Fetch Data

```
$product = Product::with('categorizable')->find(2);
$product->categorizable; //this will be either Record, Cloth... instance
```

Similarly for record

```
$record = Record::with('products')->find(1);
$record->products; //it will give you product collection
```

For details you can look https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. Just one thing: In the example you provided you showed me how to insert data into the product table, but what about the associated data? For instance, in the example you created the Product listing, but I still need to  add the data associated to the record (label, artist, etc). Is there a way to override the create method passing the type and according to the type passed (record in this case) invoke that model?

Comment: that is record creation, just create record as normal and then create product too and associate them. updated answer check it

Comment: @MrCujo did you try the answer ?